# FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JS heap out of memory while compiling the less files in react app project

Tags: reactjs, less, ant-design-pro

I have a project that uses less for styling which comes by antd pro lib, when i run my project initially it compiles all the files perfectly no issue while compiling at once, but whenever i change any less file or updates any less file it might perform the compiling process again in order to reflect from previous. Following are the error I encountered while updating in less files. **Note I can't update the version i am using**.

```
[6424:000001F107B10CB0]   793027 ms: Mark-sweep 2023.3 (2051.8) -> 2022.8 (2052.3) MB, 4134.0 / 0.1 ms  (average mu = 0.048, current mu = 0.003) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[6424:000001F107B10CB0]   794755 ms: Mark-sweep 2023.8 (2052.3) -> 2022.9 (2052.3) MB, 1714.0 / 0.1 ms  (average mu = 0.036, current mu = 0.008) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
```

JS stack trace

```
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

I was expecting that the compilation process for less files should not gives any error.

I tried to make node memory size large but did not work